# How to get a list of leafs in this tree? Problem in OCaml

Tags: tree, ocaml

We are given a tree with the type:

```
type ('nonterminal, 'terminal) parse_tree =
  | Node of 'nonterminal * ('nonterminal, 'terminal) parse_tree list
  | Leaf of 'terminal
```

and the form of:

```
let t = (Node ("+", [Leaf 3; Node ("*", [Leaf 4; Leaf 5])])
```

And we are asked to write a function that takes a tree as an argument and returns a list of leafs that it finds (form left to right) so leaves t = [3;4;5]

Now this is what I have but it gives me an error and I am unsure on how should I approach this problem:

```
let rec getleaf tree = 
  match tree with
  |Leaf a -> [a]
  | Node (a, Leaf (h)::t) -> h::getleaf t;;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What specific error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list pattern `h :: t` binds `h` to the head of the list (a single element) and `t` to the tail of the list (which is itself a list). So the name `t` in your code is going to match a list of parse trees. But `getleaf` is expecting a single parse tree as its argument.

**Update**

The usual thing to do would probably be to have `getleaf` accept a single tree. In the code for `Node` you would have to have an arbitrary number of recursive calls that you then combine to produce the result for that one node.

The most idiomatic way to handle the multiple recursive calls would be with a fold (IMHO). You can also use `List.map` (which would give a list of lists), then `List.concat` to get back to a single list. This is easier to think about (IMHO) but it does some unnecessary computation.

You might want to think about whether you need to maintain the order of the leaves.

Comment: I see, then how do you suggest I fix that? Do you think I should pass the original tree as a list?

Comment: If I pass the tree as a list and use this function I get a match_failure exception:
  let rec getleaf t = 
  match t with 
  | Node (hh,h1::t1)::tl -> h1::getleaf t1;;

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to handle the case of an empty list. The compiler will issue a warning for this. (The type system allows OCaml compiler warnings to be extremely useful, not just noise.)